# FCM upstream messages with collapse key

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send time-critical upstream messages.

Noticed that, `FirebaseMessaging.Send` Method uses collapse keys as well.

Let's say, I have 1 messages are in upstream queue and my XMPPserver is down.
Now, If a collapsible message is sent-upstream, will it replace the previous message, or wait till it fills the 20 msg- limit queue?

If this is documented somewhere, it would be good to know, or I will need to test this here

Comment: Any results on this? :)